# Agregar clase a un indice especifico en un iterable ngFor

Tags: angular

Buen día.

Tengo una lista que armo usando un ngfor - cuando hacen click en uno de sus elementos activo una bandera (active como true) y quiero agregarle la clase active de bootstrap solo a ese elemento, pero aunque obtengo el indice del elemento y se que estoy tocando uno en especifico la clase se le agrega a todos los elementos del arreglo.

```
 <ul>
   <li class="list-group" *ngFor="let link of links; let i = index">
      <i class="list-group-item note" (click)="selectLink(i)" [ngClass]="{'active':active}">
           {{link.title}}</i>
         </li>
 </ul>
```

No logro ver que estoy haciendo mal, esperaba que el ngclass funcionará solo en el elemento sobre el que hago click

Comment: la variable `active` que es? el indice del elemento activo? si es así te falta comparar el indice activo con el actual. `[ngClass]="{'active':active === i}"`

Comment: active es un boolean para activar/desactivarlo al hacer click.
Basicamente quiero es que si hacen click, active pasa a true. de esta manera el NgClass le coloque la clase, active(de bootstrap)

Comment: Gracias @hawks pude corregir gracias a tu comentario, cambie la variable active para darle el valor del indice seleccionado, y hago la comparación como lo comentaste y me funciona. [ngClass]="{'active': active === i}" [id]="i"> - antes active era un boolean ahora active = index del ngfor

Answer (score 0):

Anteriormente estaba tomando active como un boolean que activaba al hacer click, ahora cambie la variable para que tome el valor del indice del ngfor, y con el ngClass le asigno la propiedad active(de boostrap) cuando la variable active === al indice.
Para enlaces se suele usar el routerlink y routerlink-active que resuelve este mismo caso, pero necesitaba una manera de hacerlo para cualquier iterable aunque no fuera un enlace.